# New monitor keeps switching to 1024x768

Tags: kubuntu, display, display-resolution

I recently got a new monitor and it occasionally switches from 1920x1080 to 1024x768. When I go to the Display Configuration settings after it happens, anything above 1024x768 is no longer available as an option (*i.e.*, the dropdown menu goes from 640 to 1024 and no higher). After rebooting, "1920x1080" is available in system settings again.

I am running Kubuntu 20.04 with KDE Plasma 5.18.8.

I haven't been able to determine what triggers this behavior. Updating has caused it once or twice, but not always. Switching to TTY2-TTY6 always causes it.

That's not very much to go on, but this is quite frustrating. I'm a newcomer to Kubuntu/Linux and I know very little about hardware, but I like reading documentation -- I just don't know where to start looking and I need a nudge in the right direction. X11? Drivers? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt anyone else has the same problem, but in case you do, I fixed this by running at startup:

```
xrandr --size 1920x1080
```